# git blame - fatal: bad revision '22'

Tags: git, powershell, git-blame

According to this page (http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git
) I should use a comma between line numbers when using `git blame`.

However, if I try it out on my Windows machine using Powershell:

```
git blame -L 12,22 <name of file>
```

I get `fatal: bad revision '22'`

What's the problem? Something to do with Powershell?

Comment: Try quoting `-L "12,22"`? Commas mean something to powershell so it might be mishandling that.

Comment: What version of git are you using? Can you run this outside of PowerShell (through `cmd.exe` for example)?

Comment: @EtanReisner spot on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try quoting the argument to `-L` (e.g. `-L "12,22"`).

Comma is an operator in powershell so it is probably mis-parsing the command without the quotes or something like that.